# Php - Resetting initial id in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array here:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Question**: How do I reset the items' `id` when it goes to second array?
I've been trying to squeeze my head for an algorithm for this, but couldn't find a way :(

This is my source code of how I get the array if it helps. I've simplified the array for clarity, below code is the extended one:

```
$results = array();

$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $i++;
    $results[] = array(
                $row['id'] => array(
                            'category' => $row['category'],
                            'items' => array(
                                array(
                                    'id' => $i, //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                                    'name' => $row['name'],
                                    'user_name' => $row['user_name'],
                                    'price' => $row['price'],
                                    'item_photo' => $row['item_photo'],
                                    'item_description' => $row['item_description']
                                )
                            )
                )
    );

}

// Begin rebuilding trees

$output = array();

//$results is array from mysql
foreach ($results as $data) {
    //var_dump($data);
    //dumping each block of array
    foreach ($data as $categoryId => $item) {
        //check if NOT yet set
        if (!isset($output[$categoryId])) {
            //insert values in the first Array()
            $output[$categoryId] = array(
                'id'       => $categoryId,
                'category' => $item['category'],
                'items'    => array()
            );
        }

        //populate 'items' array with stuff
        $output[$categoryId]['items'] = 
        array_merge(
            $output[$categoryId]['items'],
            $item['items']
        );
    }
}
```

If anything please let me know.

Comment: I meant, I want to reset the key `[id]` to 1 after the first array. That key is in `[items]` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your results are sorted so each category's items are sequential (one category doesn't show up in different places in your results):

```
$oldCat = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

// If the current category is different than the previous, reset $i
if ($row['category'] != $oldCat)
    $i == 0;

// Set $oldCat to the current categery (used for next loop's comparison)
$oldCat = $row['category'];

$i++;
$results[] = array(
       [ ... ]
)

}
```

Also, you could make setting `$i` into a one-liner:

```
// If the current category is different than the previous, reset $i
$i = $row['category'] != $oldCat ? 0 : $i++;
```

---

Just a note for clarity, you may want to make slightly more descriptive array keys. For example, you have `id` twice - this could be `category_id` and `item_id`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll figure about the keys later. The longer solution works. However, your one-liner solution returned all IDs to 0 even if I put $oldCat before or after the line. That's okay anyway.

Comment: `$oldCat = $row['category'];` should go immediately after the one-liner. Strange that it didn't work.. Well, glad the longer solution worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

***Firstly, and most importantly, please refrain from using the `mysql_*` API as these functions are now deprecated. Instead, please use either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (personally, I would use PDO as it supports various database connections, but this is just my opinion)***

All you need to do to solve your problem with the `id` is store the previous id in a variable and test for it. The following is probably not correct as your code is pretty confusing but it should be enough to get you on the right track:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // Only increment i if it is still the same row
    // otherwise reset it
    if($row_id==$row['id']){
        $i++;
    }else{
        $i = 0;
    }
    // Set the new row id
    $row_id = $row['id'];
    // Do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks yours worked too. Anyway, I'm planning to migrate to `mysqli*` later on. Thanks for the heads up.